# Ability to double-click multiple values and populate multiple rows in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main sheet/form and a separate sheet that lists different codes. Right now, when I already have a code in the first cell of the column (C7) and want to double-click a second code to populate the next row (C8) the second code overwrites the first code in cell C7 rather than going down to the next available row, C8. Is there a way, after double-clicking a code in a separate sheet, to get it to go the next available row in the C column, Range C7:C446?

The issue I am having is, when I try to populate multipe rows within the C column I can only populate the first cell C7 and not the other cells in the range C7:C446. 
Here is the code for the main sheet:

```
Option Explicit
Public sourceRange As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C7:D446")) Is Nothing Then
      Dim c As Range: Set c = Range("D7:D446")
'     For Each c In Target
 For Each c In c.Cells
          Select Case c.Value
              Case "1000GP", "1000MM", "19FEST", "20IEDU", "20ONLC", "20PART", "20PRDV", "20SPPR", "22DANC", "22LFLC", "22MEDA", "530CCH", "60POUBL", "74GA01", "74GA17", "74GA99", "78REDV"
                  Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
              Case Else
                 Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
          End Select
      Next c

' End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Set sourceRange = Nothing ' Set it to nothing to avoid too long remembering
  If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
      Set sourceRange = Target ' Remember source cell
      'Cancel = True
      Select Case Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
        Case "1000GP": gotoref1
        Case "1000MM": gotoref2
        Case "19FEST": gotoref3
        Case "20IEDU": gotoref4
        Case "20ONLC": gotoref5
        Case "20PART": gotoref6
        Case "20PRDV": gotoref7
        Case "20SPPR": gotoref8
        Case "22DANC": gotoref9
        Case "22LFLC": gotoref10
        Case "22MEDA": gotoref11
        Case "530CCH": gotoref12
        Case "60PUBL": gotoref13
        Case "74GA01": gotoref14
        Case "74GA17": gotoref15
        Case "74GA99": gotoref16
        Case "78REDV": gotoref17
      End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code for the sheet with the codes listed below. I know the issue is probabl becuase I have the code set to `.Range("C7")` but I tried doing `.Range("C7:C446)` but that didn't work :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Column = 1 Then
Worksheets("JE").Range("C7").Value = ActiveCell.Value    
Worksheets("JE").Activate

Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please STOP posting multiple questions on the same topic - stick with the original until it's clear things are not going to work out.  You now have 8 questions all on this same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    For j = 7 to 446
        If Worksheets("JE").Range("C" & j).Value = "" Then
             Worksheets("JE").Range("C" & j).Value = ActiveCell.Value    
             Worksheets("JE").Activate
             Exit For
        End If
     Next j
End If

Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I Implemented this code but when I double-click on a code, it populates the cell C448 as the first cell,  not C7 (which is the first cell)

Comment: Are there values already in the cells C7:C447 that you're just trying to overwrite?

Comment: No, those cells do not have any values in them. I would just like the first value to be in the first cell C7, then the second on cell C8, and so on.

Comment: `lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1` finds the last cell in column C with text in it and marks the next available cell for data entry. According to what you've told me, nothings in cell 447, but something must be there since it tried to start placing code in C448. But you're saying C447 is empty?

Comment: Try my new solution. It'll loop through all cells in C7 - C447 until it finds an empty one, then place you value in it.

Comment: You're right there is text in cell C447, it is the last row in the form and it is text that reads "Total". I believe I need that there. Is there a way to specify a cell range in the C column to be C7:C446 rather than the entire column? Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel this answer solved your issue, please go ahead and mark it as accepted.